# Get all kendo dropdown inside a div

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I am struggling to get all kendo dropdowns inside a div.

If I use

```
$(".k-list-container").each(function () { 
  var elementId = this.id.split("-")[0]; 
  var cb = $("#" + elementId).data("kendoDropDownList"); 
  if(cb){    
     // do operation on dropdown 
   } 
}
```

it gets all kendo drop down of page, I want to get only for a div.

I tried

```
$("#mydiv .k-list-container").each(function () {
```

and several other selectors but it did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a .find on the div you want to search?

```
$("#myDiv").find(".k-list-container{
```

Comment: Does it needs to be a comment?

Comment: yes ,it wont work because kendo creates .k-list-container outside the location where you create control, on click by jquery they display these elements as dropdown. In short .k-list-container is not child of div.